# Unable to compile a JUnit test on Windows

Tags: java, junit, compilation

I'm trying to compile this very simple JUnit test on my Windows 10 box:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestHelloWorld
{
    @Test
    public void BasicTest ()
    {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

However, this seemingly innocuous task has proven impervious to three to four hours of research and trial and error.

From a Cygwin terminal I see this:

```
javac -cp lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/lib/junit-4.12.jar:. TestHe
TestHelloWorld.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
                       ^
TestHelloWorld.java:1: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
^
TestHelloWorld.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
TestHelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        @Test
         ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class TestHelloWorld
TestHelloWorld.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                assertTrue(true);
                ^
  symbol:   method assertTrue(boolean)
  location: class TestHelloWorld
5 errors
```

and from a CMD prompt I see this:

```
javac -cp C:\Users\canon\Documents\GitHub\cse1341\AssignmentTester\lib\junit.jar TestHelloWorld.java
error: error reading C:\Users\canon\Documents\GitHub\cse1341\AssignmentTester\lib\junit.jar; error in opening zip file
1 error
```

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing incorrectly here. I've always been on a *nix machine before, where I don't recall having any problems compiling JUnit tests when I pass in the junit and hamcrest jars to the class path using the -cp flag. Any ideas or guidance here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you user `canon`? If not, then you're not authorized to read that file. Otherwise, the jar file might be corrupt. Try getting it again.

Comment: I am the canon user, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing:

- Java in windows using ';' to separate the jar files in classpath argument so it should be
  "javac -cp lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;/lib/junit-4.12.jar;. TestHeTestHelloWorld.java" in cygwin
- check if C:\Users\canon\Documents\GitHub\cse1341\AssignmentTester\lib\junit.jar is a valid jar. (you can use zip tool to check).

Answer (score 0):

The slash before `lib/junit-4.12.jar` seems to be wrong.